# What is the best way to implement Here SDK for React Native apps (iOS and Android)?

Tags: react-native, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk

Is there an existing React-Native library to implement Here maps and navigation, or do I have to implement the Here SDKs natively for both platforms?

Comment: Alternatively, consider to use Flutter. There's an SDK for this: https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore

Comment: @Datasun we are adding the map feature to an existing react native app, so unfortunately using the here flutter sdk at this point is not possible. Also, our tech lead has ruled out using mapbox sdk, so implementing Here maps in react native is our only option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement native module for both iOS and Android to use Here SDK from React Native apps. If you are using HERE SDK 3.x, following would be a good example how to do it.
https://github.com/Weopt/react-native-here-maps

If you are using HERE SDK 4.x, you need some modification to the above example to adjust the difference of the interface between 3.x and 4.x.

Comment: Can you provide a running example for iOS for 4.x then it will be helpful?